# ms-Access combo box query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that I am trying to get to update based on a query. Under criteria I've put `[Forms]![Form Name]![Combo Box]`
Whenever I choose a different option in the combo box, nothing updates. How do I make the for update?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the criteria section.  Then, in the OnChange event of the dropdown, put this:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyFieldName = " & [Forms]![Form Name]![Combo Box] & ""

Me.Requery
```

Obviously, you need to change the name of the table and field, I just used generic names since I don't know what they are called in your database.

Comment: When I run it, it says, "Run-error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Comment: I figured out the run-time error, but I guess I should have mentioned the rest of what I'm trying to do, because I'm having a problem with that now. CB2 is supposed to update all the textboxes with the '="[ID] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))' macro. Whenever I change something on CB1, it doesn't update CB2 and CB2 stops updating everything else.